# mysql - installing or upgrading mysql 5.5 to 5.6 in Linux mint

Tags: mysql, upgrade

Following error message getting while upgrading from Mysql 5.5 to 5.6.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   mysql-client-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-core-5.6 but it is not going to   be installed
>   mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (=
>   5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which was solved after update and upgrade.
Try this, I hope this works for you:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Comment: I've got this problem and am getting `Unable to locate package mysql-server-5.6`

Answer (score 0):

> Installing MySQL 5.6 on Linux(debian based distro):

Uninstall any existing version of MySQL:

**sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-***

**mysql-client-core-***

**sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql**

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

**sudo apt-get autoclean**

Automatically uninstall mysql:

**sudo apt-get autoremove mysql* --purge**
**sudo apt-get remove apparmor**

Download version 5.5.51 from MySQL site

wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz

Add mysql user group:

**sudo groupadd mysql**

Add mysql (not the current user) to mysql user group:

**sudo useradd -g  mysql mysql**

Extract mysql-5.6.*-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz to /usr/local:

**cd /usr/loca**l
**sudo tar -xvf mysql-5.6.*-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz**

Create mysql folder in /usr/local:

**sudo mv mysql-5.6.*-linux2.6-x86_64 mysql**

Set mysql directory owner and user group:

**cd mysql**
**sudo chown -R mysql:mysql * **

Install the required lib package:

**sudo apt-get install libaio1**

Execute mysql installation script:

**sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql**

Set mysql directory owner from outside the mysql directory:

**sudo chown -R root .**

Set data directory owner from inside mysql directory:

**sudo chown -R mysql data**

Copy the mysql configuration file :

**sudo cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf**

Start mysql:

**sudo bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &**
**sudo cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server**

Initialize root user password:

**sudo bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'test'**

Start mysql server:

**sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start**
**Stop mysql server**

**sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server stop**

Check status of mysql:

**sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server status**

Enable myql on startup:

**sudo update-rc.d -f mysql.server defaults**

Add mysql path to the system:

**sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql**

Now directly use the command below to start mysql

**mysql -u root -p**